# Can I import roasted soybeans (edamame) into the EU without a health certificate?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, eu

According to [French customs](https://www.douane.gouv.fr/sites/default/files/2021-03/10/travellers-what-kinds-of-food-and-plants-can-you-bring-with-you.pdf), plants and products can be imported under the following conditions:

> - You must
>   present a plant
>   health certificate
>   from the country
>   of origin

Does this also apply to fried/roasted vegetables that are commercially packaged? I'm looking to import a kilo of roasted edamame from the US but not sure if that still requires a health certificate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the EU Regulation on food products exempt from customs control  [(link)](http://data.europa.eu/eli/reg_del/2019/2122/oj), if any food item

- it *does not contain any milk nor meat*
- and *it is for personal use*

it is exempt from control:

> ### Article 7
>
> Goods which form part of passengers’ personal luggage and are intended for personal consumption or use
> *(omissis)*
>
> Products of animal origin, composite products, products derived from animal by-products, plants, plant products and other objects which form part of passengers’ personal luggage and which are intended for personal consumption or use, are exempted from official controls at border control posts provided that they belong to at least one of the following categories:
>
> *(omissis)*
>
> (c) goods other than those referred to in points (a) and (b) of this article and other than those referred to in Part 2 of Annex I, provided that their combined quantity does not exceed the weight limit of 2 kg;
>
> (d) plants, other than plants for planting, plant products and other objects;
>
> ### Annex I part 2
>
> *(omissis)*
>
> ex 2005:
> Other vegetables prepared or preserved otherwise than by vinegar or acetic acid, not frozen, other than products of heading 2006. Note: Only those preparations containing meat or milk, or both.

So looks like that 1 kg is fine.